# GraySquare: exp:channel:entries does not show all entries

Tags: channel-entries, channel

I have a page that shows tips by month. It works well but for some odd reason, the `{exp:channel:entries channel="tips"}` does not return all tips.

I query the database:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT t.entry_id AS query_entry_id FROM 
exp_channel_titles t, exp_channel_data d WHERE t.entry_id = d.entry_id 
and t.year='{segment_3}' and t.month='{segment_4}' and t.channel_id='3' 
order by t.entry_date desc"}
```

then use `{exp:channel:entries channel="tips"}`. `{total_results)` shows 4 but the same tip is repeated 4 times instead of 4 different tips.

Here is the URL to understand better:
http://www.neatfreak.com/index.php/site/tips/2014/07/

Bottom line, I have around 85 tips but it only shows a few. The dates and the channel on all tips are correct.

Comment: Are the status of all tips `open`?

Comment: Thanks Robson Sobral, yes! the status of all tips are open.

Answer (score 1):

show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="no" helped !

Comment: I didn't suggest that because you said the dates are correct. Glad you find the solution.

Comment: Thanks Robson. The status of all tips is still open, looking at your answer I guessed that maybe the end date was specified on the tips and the system might be considering it expired.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing dates in URLs is automatic in EE; you don't need to build a query for that: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/212166/